# postgres how to materialize a row for each value in an enum array

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres table that stores recurring appointments called `appointments`. I also have an enum type called `day_of_week`.

`day_of_week` is an enum that looks like:

```
select enum_range(null::ck_day_of_week);
```

returns

```
{Monday,Tuesday,Thursday,Sunday,Saturday,Friday,Wednesday}
```

The appointments table's DDL is:

```
create table appointments
(
    id serial primary key not null,
    title varchar not null
    recurrence_start_date timestampz not null,
    recurrence_end_date timestampz,
    recurrence_days_of_week _ck_day_of_week  -- this is actually an array of enums, not just an enum. I don't fully understand why the DDL looks like this
);
```

A query of

```
select id, title, recurrence_days_of_week from appointments where recurrence_start_date <= now() and (recurrence_end_date is null or recurrence_end_date >= now());
```

returns something like this:

```
1,My Recurring Appointment,{Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday}
```

My question is, I need to 'materialize' this result as a set of rows for my UI view. Specifically I'd like to query the DB and have it return rows like:

```
id,My Recurring Appointment,date
```

where a unique key would likely be the appointment id and specific `date` and where `date` is a essentially a combination of recurrence_start_date + day of week (day of week is an offset between 0 and 6).

In postgres, how do I select from a table that has a column which is an enum array and have it return a --virtual-- single row of the --real-- same row for each enum value in the array? I'm thinking of a view or something, but I'm now sure how to write the select statement.

Bonus points if this can be translated into SQLAlchemy....

I'm also open and have considered just creating an appointments table that stores each appointment with its specific date. But if I do this...in theory, for appointments with recurring dates where there is no end date, the table could be infinitely large, so I've been trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd not suggest using `id` as a column name ever.

Second, I'd use built in date/time functions to achieve the 1st objective. More specificly the combination `extract` function with `dow` parameter (*day of week*) and `generate_series` function with.

Make sure to check fiddle in the **References** section.

Query returning list of `appointments` for each day of week:

```
create or replace function fnc_appointment_list_dow_by_id(_app_id int)
    returns table (__app_id int, __title varchar, __recurrence_start_date timestamptz, __recurrence_appointment_day timestamptz, __reccurence_dow_offset int) as
$body$
        select
                app.app_id,
                app.app_title,
                app.app_recurrence_start_date,
                _appointment_days._day,
                extract(dow from _day)::int
            from
                appointments app,
                generate_series(app.app_recurrence_start_date, app.app_recurrence_end_date, interval '1 day') _appointment_days(_day)
            where app.app_id=_app_id;
$body$
    language sql stable; -- consider changing function volatility as needed.

-- select * from fnc_appointment_list_dow_by_id(1);
```

Query returning array of appointment days of week:

```
create or replace function fnc_appointment_array_dow_by_id(_app_id int)
        returns table (__app_id int, __title varchar, __recurrence_start_date timestamptz, __recurrence_appointment_day timestamptz[], __reccurence_dow_offset int[]) as
    $body$
        select
                app.app_id,
                app.app_title,
                app.app_recurrence_start_date,
                array_agg(_day::timestamptz),
                array_agg(extract(dow from _day)::int)
            from
                appointments app,
                generate_series(app.app_recurrence_start_date, app.app_recurrence_end_date, interval '1 day') as _appointment_days(_day)
            where app.app_id=_app_id
            group by app.app_id, app.app_title, app.app_recurrence_start_date;
    $body$
        language sql stable; -- consider changing function volatility as needed.

-- select * from fnc_appointment_array_dow_by_id(1);
```

If either of functions is what you are looking for let me know and we can move on to next objectives.

**References**:

- [Documentation on date/time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) (look for `extract`
  function)
- [Documentation on generate_series functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) (look for
  `generate_series` function with arguments of `timestamp` type)
- [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f6fa7/4) (Don't mind array of `timestamptz` being displayed as array of `int`s)

Comment: Super big thanks for such helpful reply. This actually got me to where I needed to be although -I think- it kinda skirted the array enum column I have. The first thing I needed though was to unnest {Monday,Tuesday,Thursday,Sunday,Saturday,Friday,Wednesday} for each activity. Once I had that I was able to use the concepts you mentioned, like extract and generate_series to generate recurrences.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Cheers.